# How to execute the command only when starting a dll?

Tags: c++, c, dll

I have an executable that when started, loads a dll.

```
void PHP_New_Tread(){ 
    CreateThread(NULL,NULL,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(PHP_Autentication),NULL,0,0);
}
```

```
void PHP_con(){ 
    again:
    PHP_Autentication();
    PHP_New_Tread(); 
    Sleep(60000);   
    goto again; 
}
```

```
void HTTP_Connect(){
    CreateThread(NULL,NULL,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(PHP_con),NULL,0,0);
}
```

The `PHP_Autentication` function takes information and sends it via POST using a php.

I would like this function to be called only when the application starts.

If I use sleep, it only runs the first time when a certain amount of time has passed. And whenever time passes, it will perform.

If I leave without sleep, it sends dozens of information per minute.

The line that runs this whole structure is this

```
if(carrega.Splash_Screen == 1){
SplashShow(); HTTP_Connect();
}
```

Can someone help me? The dll was written in C ++

Comment: you flag `C` but tell this is in `C++` this is two different languages.

Comment: For the life of me, I have no idea what you're asking. Which application? Which DLL? Who is calling `PHP_con`? Why is there a `goto`? Please read [ask] and try to explain clearly what you're doing in a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

the goto is like an infinite loop, just remove it:

```
void PHP_con(){ 
    PHP_Autentication();
    PHP_New_Tread();      
}
```